# Trying to add horizontal slider ranger bar in Java EE

Tags: intellij-idea, primefaces, xhtml, java-ee-6

I am trying to add prime face slider horizontal bar from this link in my xhtml file of JAVA EE: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/slider.xhtml?jfwid=fa7b8

the code is :

```
  <h5 class="p-mt-0">Basic</h5>
            <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
                <p:inputText id="txt" value="#{sliderView.number1}"/>
                <p:slider for="txt" range="false"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
```

but i am getting error like: Error Parsing /beergame_user.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 116] The prefix "p" for element "p:inputText" is not bound and same for p:slider.

my head tags are same as indicated in documentation of prime face which are:

but still the error is showing.

Comment: <html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to add JSF slider range bar in xhtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67242815/trying-to-add-jsf-slider-range-bar-in-xhtml)

Comment: Looks like you are missing the Primefaces namespace `xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"`

Comment: @Melloware added the namespace, but it is appearing in red

Comment: That namespace appearing in red is an odd IntelliJ thing.  Sometimes you have to reload your project. or update to a newer IntelliJ fixed that issue for me.