# Trying to add PrimeFaces slider results in "Cannot resolve symbol 'p:slider'"

Tags: jsf, primefaces, slider

I am trying to add PrimeFaces slider in Facelets, but the error keeps popping stating: *Cannot resolve symbol 'p:slider'*

I am following the documentation with headers and all pre-requisites but still the error is there.

```
           <h:outputText id="displayRange" value="Between #{sliderBean.number6} and #{sliderBean.number7}"/>
            <p:slider for="txt6,txt7" display="displayRange" style="width:400px" range="true" displayTemplate="Between {min} and {max}"/>
            <h:inputHidden id="min" value="#{sliderBean.min}" />
            <h:inputHidden id="max" value="#{sliderBean.max}" />>
```

Comment: Follow https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/getstarted.xhtml and do a clean build

Comment: Clone https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test and go from there